# Android Studio - How to import asset and preserve its color?

Tags: android, android-studio, assets

Every time I try to import asset via **Asset Studio** in Android studio, I get to choose only from 3 options of Asset Type - **Launcher Icons**, **Action Bar and Tab Icons** and **Notification Icons**. Only the **Launcher Icons** can preserve the original color of png and create `m/x/.../dpi` icons, but it puts them into the `mipmap` folder.

How should I import my custom colourful png icon so that Android Studio just creates lower dpi clones and preserves all the colors?